# Camera HP Photosmart M307 with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hp, camera

Can I use a HP Photosmart M307 camera under Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this specific camera but if you have a look at this page:

[Digital Camera Support for UNIX, Linux and BSD](http://www.teaser.fr/~hfiguiere/linux/digicam.html)

you will see the HP PhotoSmart M307 listed as supported by Linux in general, no specific mention of distro or release version unfortunately. However it is marked down as able to be used as a Mass Storage USB Device so at the very least you should be able to drag photographs off the device using a file manager...